# IE 11 auto accepts the alert pop up

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, test-automation-framework, nodejs

So I am on an edit page and when I click the cancel button to stay on the edit page the `IE` driver automatically accepts the leave page in alert pop up. I even added the `IE capabilities` saying:

```
options = new ie.Options();
options.setAlertBehavior('ignore');
```

But it still auto-accepts the alert dialog.  Is there a way I can stop this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

If you read through the NOTE section of the dismiss action in webdriver https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dismiss-alert - says

> A request to dismiss an alert user prompt, which may not necessarily
>   have a dismiss button, has the same effect as accepting it.

Could you please try out 2 things?

1. Try the same event on a different browser and see the result.
2. Talk to the developer and figure out if there is a dismiss event associated with the CANCEL button, if not add it. (I guess this could be the case)

This should have been a comment as it requires some action on your end and the solution  might vary based on your findings, but due to the limitation on the words I am writing this as a solution.

Comment: It works in Chrome, but I wanna make it work in IE 11. Developer says there is no dismiss event associated with the Cancel Button. For some reason, when I hit Cancel button it takes me back to the Main Page which I dont want. It seems like IE driver automatically closes the dialog. And the setAlertBehavior is set to "ignore", but still accepts the dialog